# How to submit tracking number on external courier website using php or ajax or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there any way to open an external courier website link and submit the tracking form and get the result page in popup / model / iframe ?
Here is the link from which I want to get the tracking result: https://www.tcsexpress.com/tracking. 
How to do this using php / ajax / javascript and I want to make tracking number as variable.

This is my html javascript and css code and also I have tracking in php variable

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('popupiframe').src = "https://www.tcsexpress.com/tracking";
  document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
  };
  return false;
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 12%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}

#popup iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

#popupdarkbg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <a href="" id="link">Click me</a><br>
</div>

<div id="popup"><iframe id="popupiframe"></iframe></div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

and this is my tracking code in PHP variable

```
$dvs_courier_tracking = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_dvs_courier_tracking', true );
```

I am creating a plugin in WordPress.

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show your effort and HTML you plan to use

Comment: @mplungjan Sir I have updated the question with my code.

Comment: You need to find out if they support a format like `https://www.tcsexpress.com/tracking?trackno=12345`

Answer (score 0):

If the site supports it there are multiple ways to "post" this information to the endpoint, perhaps check if tcsexpress pregenerate tracking codes themselves likely using a query string on the end of their endpoint, i.e.

```
https://www.tcsexpress.com/tracking?exampleTrackingId=ABCD1234
```

If they *do not* support anything like that, or have an API they can provide you, then the "hacky" way of doing this would be to use a library like [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/) which allows you to programmatically perform events and crawl sites. The downsides to this are:

- Most sites don't want bots using up their bandwidth excessively, it's likely there are T&Cs which prohibit this and the site may actively ban associated IPs of bots or employ methods like ReCaptcha to validate human input
- Websites change often, where an API is (largely) guaranteed to be dependable, the structure of the page changing could break your script
- Performance wise this is adding a few extra layers to your requests, so it's not exactly going to be the fastest

Basically I'd recommend simply contacting tcsexpress to confirm they already have this functionality in the form of a query string (likely), and then you can open a new tab/window etc. with that URL.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I have updated the code, please check how to submit the form using javascript

Comment: Hi Iqbal, I do not believe you have read my answer thoroughly as you seem to have not made any attempt to find out whether the TCS endpoint supports some form of public query parameters.

If you start with that you will easily solve this yourself.